# Is there a way to configure ILogger to use single line unless message itself is multiline?

Tags: c#, ilogger

When my configuring ILogger looks like this:

```
            services.AddLogging(options =>
            {
                options.AddSimpleConsole(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleLine = false;
                });
            });
```

I will get multiline output even for simpliest messages:

```
[08T15:30:49] dbug: Lala.WebUI.Shared.DataManagerHub[0]
      SaveLanguages in 0s.
```

The first line is `ILogger` stuff, the second line is mine. OK, so I switch option to `true` and it works fine until my message is multiline -- in such cases `ILogger` default implementation squeezes everything into single line.

So my question is there an option to make the "header/prefix" and the message first line as single line. So it could look like this:

Single line message:

```
[08T15:30:49] dbug: Lala.WebUI.Shared.DataManagerHub[0] SaveLanguages in 0s.
```

Multiline message:

```
[08T15:30:49] dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[4] Hosting stopped
Unhandled exception. Xunit.Sdk.FailException: Assert.Fail(): An error occurred while saving the entity changes. SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'. from MeasureAsync in /home/mist/Projekty/lala/app/Lala.WebUI.Shared/CommonPostDataWorkerBase.cs at line 45
```

Comment: You don't want to configure `ILogger`, you want to configure the Console log formatted. However, I don't think you can do this, nor can I imagine why you care. If you want proper log output, then push the logs to somewhere like App Insights where the multiline thing doesn't matter. Perhaps the Serilog console sink has something though? And if it doesn't, you could probably write your own formatter.

Comment: What happens if you set `SingleLine` true, then manually insert newlines? E.g. `LogWarning("This message will be on {nl} two lines", Environment.NewLine);` I'm not sure how the logger would know when to break the lines otherwise (considering I can set my console to have any number of characters per line).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, that's the point -- I have the newlines withing message, but with `SingleLine = true` the default logger removes them.

Comment: @DavidG I would like to stick to default logger, to avoid polluting my solution with more packages to solve such trivial tasks. I will check the custom formatter though, thank you for the tip.